# Проблема с html+css

Tags: html, css

У меня вопрос, что не так с этим кодом???

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.test {
 color: #fff;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: #555555;
 width: 675px;
 height: 700px;
}
<style>
<body>
    <div class="test">
        <div class="link"><a href="#">Test</a></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: тег style не закрыт

Comment: Во спасибо))), вот блин не обратил внимания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не закрыли тег `style`

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<style type="text/css">
.test {
 color: #fff;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: #555555;
 width: 675px;
 height: 700px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="test">
        <div class="link"><a href="#">Test</a></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас тег `<style>` находится не в `<head>` и не закрыт можете посмотреть на свой код в онлайн редакторе https://plnkr.co/edit/OkEL8OREXdxSxpeoDUtB?p=preview

Comment: Не принципиально в head пихать), это ведь черновик для набросков.
Ps. Минус не я ставил)

Comment: Согласен, но еще лучше вынести в отдельный файл, а еще лучше придерживаться https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html

Comment: Спасибо), за советы.